# How to make excel chart include all blank cells from range specified in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

In my code, I create a chart and specify a range for the input data:

```
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Output").Range("N6:CS6")
```

The problem is that the first few cells are blank sometimes and when the chart is created it ignores them and starts from the first cell containing a value. This in turn results in a mismatch between the X-axis values and the data being displayed.

How can I force the chart to include full range specified, even if it contains blank cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the blanks to display as zero the code is

```
ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlZero
```